# Getting Azure DevOps Pipeline Artifact output Windows app

Tags: azure-devops, desktop-application, azure-pipelines

Using Azure Devops.  Made pipeline using Visual Designer for .Net Desktop application.  Trying to get the output (exe).  I created a feed in the Artifacts but I don't see a way to specify it in the Pipeline configuration.  In the build output for Copy files to $(build.artifactsstagingdirectory) it shows file copied

```
2019-01-11T01:10:27.4301461Z Copying D:\a\2\s\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp\bin\Release\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp.exe to D:\a\2\a\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp\bin\Release\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp.exe
2019-01-11T01:10:27.4327361Z Copying D:\a\2\s\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp\bin\Release\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp.exe.config to D:\a\2\a\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp\bin\Release\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp.exe.config
2019-01-11T01:10:27.4335836Z Copying 
D:\a\2\s\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp\bin\Release\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp.pdb to 
D:\a\2\a\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp\bin\Release\AzureDevopsSimpleTestApp.pdb
```

The Publish Artifact step it says file uploaded successfully but where is it??  how can I download it?  Thanks!

```
2019-01-11T01:10:27.8230580Z Uploading 3 files
2019-01-11T01:10:28.1382894Z File upload succeed.
2019-01-11T01:10:28.1382985Z Upload 'D:\a\2\a' to file container: '#/672188/drop'
2019-01-11T01:10:28.1383023Z Associated artifact 2 with build 3
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3hKg.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F56M0.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnCR6.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I download it?

You could download it from  **Summary** tab. For more information, please refer to the screenshot.

[image]